# How to run CMD commands from springboot service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cmd

I'm able to run same code through a normal java class. However when I move same code to a service class in springboot, and call the service from controller on a hit of url, the command doesn't run or gets stuck for a long time.

```
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", command2).start();
    .
    .
    .
    process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
```

Tried a lot of times and different ways, still not able to find the solution.

command is

```
"tool --f pathToFile".
```

Comment: are you using full path to the file? this only works in spring boot when you write the absolute path in your command

Comment: @Paplusc yes, full path, apparently command executed successfully after 80 minutes. It took ~20 seconds if fired in a normal java project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use separate arguments and dont use entire command but break it into separate argumennts as below:

```
try {
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
            commands.add("CMD");
            commands.add("/C"); 
            commands.add("tool");
            commands.add("--f");  
            commands.add(pathToFile);
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
             try {
                    Process p = pb.start();
                    int j = p.waitFor();
                    int exitValue = p.exitValue();
                    System.out.println("Finished with code: " + j);
                    System.out.println("Finished with exitValue: " + exitValue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("exception: " + e);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work. The thing is, same code, I'm able to run in a simple java project. However when I put this in a class and annotate it as a service, call it through a controller once a specific url gets a hit. It stops half way, I tried printing it on the console, it stops in half way, In a normal java application, it takes ~20 seconds, however it's been ~20 minutes, inside spring boot application. Might be a stupid question but, I don't think this has to do something with dependencies, or does it?

Comment: can you check the file privilege ?

Comment: The code is executing successfully. The issue is time it is taking to execute.

Comment: Are you calling this on separate thread? what happened when you remove the command line execution from you service? does service return fast?